# Checking Singapore CPF account after PR expiry

Tags: singapore, cpf

I received my SPR in 2002 and expired in 2007. I did not withdraw my CPF contribution. I want to know how much I have in my account and tried to check online. I forgot my signpass password and tried to retrieve my password but the system denied stating my personal detail is invalid. How can I retrieve my account? Why the system denied my personal information as I entered correctly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP needs to contact the Help team for the system they’re trying to access

Comment: @Traveller This is about checking pension balance, not just logging in.

Answer (score 1):

If your SingPass is no longer valid, you cannot do it online, but you can contact CPF and ask them to give you a statement:

> You can also email member@cpf.gov.sg, call 1800-227-1188 or visit any of our CPF Service Centres for a printed copy of your Yearly Statement of Account. Please note that an administrative fee would be chargeable if you would like to have a copy of your statement to be mailed to you.

Source: https://www.cpf.gov.sg/members/FAQ/schemes/other-matters/others/FAQDetails?category=other+matters&group=Others&ajfaqid=2192013&folderid=13700